# Nagios: Is it possible to have multiple IPs for a host?

Tags: nagios, failover

In our office we have dual WAN setup, if our cable connection drops we still get connectivity via our T1. The only issue is that our office network is no longer available on the same IP so all Nagios check go critical because they can't connect.

What'd be awesome is if I could have Nagios try IP 1 by default but if for some reason its failing on that IP try IP 2.

I doubt this is possible with a default install but I'm wondering if there is any add-ons or some other magic that could make this work?

Comment: Why not use hostnames?

Comment: Where is your Nagios server? Are you saying that it connects to your office via the public internet to check services running within your office?

Comment: Service checks shouldn't go critical when a service becomes unreachable due to a problem on your network. You should consider setting up a [Nagios dependency](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/dependencies.html).

Comment: Nagios is installed on our infrastructure at Rackspace, it talks to all of our servers in our office over public ip via NRPE.

Comment: @sam: How should host names help here? You would need to update these if one of your connections goes down.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could use hostnames in lieu of the actual IP for the host definition - How ever that would require me to roll the IP at our DNS provider every time we switch over. Not sure that our router has any way to hook into the fail over (but it could be done as en event handler for our router check)

Comment: @MilesErickson: Using dependencies in this case would mean to monitor the whole dependency tree twice, once for each possible link.

Comment: @SvenW Should that not happen anyway? How do things use servers if they don't know where they are? You would probably need to update the IPs somewhere and using DNS is the most logical place.

Comment: @sam If our cable goes down we do lose some mail coming into our office because we don't change the IP dynamically, but we can continue to operate as normal with the slower T1 connection. We don't run much on the servers in our office that have to be accessed externally, it just so happens our nagios server is external.

Comment: @Aknosis It's a separate question, but you absolutely can provide a secondary (less-preferred) MX record to ensure that mail can arrive via your backup T1 as well as via cable.

Comment: @MilesErickson We just added the MX records which will be awesome if the cable goes down for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the check_multiaddr plugin:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/check_multiaddr/details

in my environment to execute checks against multi-homed servers.  Some servers have multiple interfaces in multiple VLANs (for traffic segmentation).  Only one interface is in DNS, so using hostnames in the Nagios config wasn't applicable to me.  I originally started with multiple host definitions with separate IPs (host-a, host-a-vlan1) but that proved cumbersome.

I modified the check_multiaddr slightly to throw a CRITICAL if any of the interfaces is down because the default (OK as long as one interface is up) didn't meet my scenario.

Comment: This basically does what @SvenW suggested but consolidates it to only changing the arguments for each command. This is probably one step better than defining multiple host entries which just feels wrong. And for me - this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Configure a primary and backup VPN tunnel between your offsite Nagios server and your office LAN. Let Nagios check services using the *private* IP address of each, using whichever VPN tunnel is available. Configure a dependency on the VPN endpoint so that service checks go "unknown" and not "critical" if both VPN links go down.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of work (or a lot, if your system is large), you could put every check inside a wrapper check script that tests the service in question on both possible addresses.

Comment: I know I can do this but it would make it overly cumbersome every time I need to add a new check

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on exactly what you're monitoring. There are plugins that can handle multi-homed hosts (the stock check_icmp, for example), but if you're checking any services, or using SNMP/NRPE/whatever, you need to get fancier.

You could cobble together something using [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start), maintain two parallel configurations that are all children of the two different WAN connections, or look into [adaptive monitoring](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/adaptive.html).